# PHP Upload Files

Tags: php, ubuntu, upload

Всем привет.

При попытке загрузки файлов: rar, pdf, exe - PHP возвращает ошибку 7 UPLOAD_ERR_CANT_WRITE. При этом txt, ppt, gif и другие загружает нормально.

Проблема встречается на внутреннем сервере под Ubuntu 14.04 + apache2, php 5.6

У нормального хостера :) все работает великолепно.

Очевидно есть пробел в знаниях и конфигурации apache/php, но пока я не вижу решения проблемы. Коллеги, если есть понимания в какую сторону копать - прошу направить.

Спасибо.

Для примера, скрипт вообще элементарный:

index.php

```
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">  
    <input type="file" name="filename" class="form-control">
    <button type="submit">Отправить</button>
</form>
```

upload.php

```
print_r($_FILES);
```

Comment: Проверьте если можете писать фаил в диреkторию где upload.php находится

Comment: @L.Vadim дак если другие файлы загружаются?

Comment: @teran Ошибка, о пермишинс - тут не может быть, что то другое.

Comment: проверяйте на разных размеров файлов, а потом смотрите какие-нибудь расширения вида `mod_security`

Answer (score 0):

Судя по ошибке проблема в сохранении файлов. Проверьте директории в которые пытаетесь сохранить файлы.

```
UPLOAD_ERR_CANT_WRITE

Value: 7; Failed to write file to disk. Introduced in PHP 5.1.0.
```

Источник: http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php

UPD. Проверьте всё таки доступна ли папка для записи [is_writable](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-writable.php).

Так же возможно что вы грузите слишком большие файлы и они не помещаются во временную папку /tmp или какая у вас заданна в php.ini.
Попробуйте в php.ini изменить `upload_tmp_dir` на путь к папке где у вас точно есть много свободного места.

Comment: Согласен, но как это можно отдебажить? И почему ошибка с запись файла на диск появляется только для определенных типов файла: rar, pdf, exe... Возможно есть какие то дополнительные библиотеки MIME которые стоит доустановить. Где то в интернетах говорили про: sudo apt-get install php-mime-type - но пока желаемого результата я не получил.

Comment: Это не много не то, дополнил ответ, пробуйте

Comment: Ага, тоже думал что места не хватает для временных файлов, заменил: upload_tmp_dir = /tmp на upload_tmp_dir = /var/www/tmp
на время дебага chmod 777 /var/www/tmp. Так же остальные изменения php.ini - немного увеличил значения
post_max_size = 80M; 
upload_max_filesize = 80M; 
memory_limit = 512M; 
max_execution_time = 130; 
memory_limit = 256M;
Положительного результата пока не получил. Увы.

Comment: Как вариант найти мелкий pdf или rar файл до 1Мб к примеру и попробовать залить, если не зальется тогда даже не знаю чем помочь, что-то вы упускаете :)

Comment: Размер файлов для тестов ~1 мб. Аналогичные по размеру файлы но в другом формате загружаются.

Comment: Значит скорее всего проблема в post_max_size, upload_max_filesize, memory_limit. Попробуйте их увеличить до 256 к примеру или ещё больше.

Comment: Увеличил до 1500M - не помогло. Обратил внимание, что успешные файлы грузятся во временную директорию:  [tmp_name] => /tmp/phpqUhztS, т.е. в /tmp, а не /var/www/tmp - пошел думать как назначить корректно директорию для временных файлов...

Comment: Может забыли перегрузить apache или если у вас nginx то php-fpm

Answer (score 0):

Дебажа ini_get() и sys_get_temp_dir () обнаружил две проблемы.
Во первых по какой то причине в /tmp временно не помещались некоторые типы файлов: rar, pdf, exe...
Починил изменив на /var/www/tmp

Во вторых, как не правил php.ini все равно оставалось:
post_max_size   8M
upload_max_filesize 2M

В общем и целом, мне не понятна логика, но смог переопределить настройки только для виртуального хоста /etc/apache2/sites-available/

```
php_admin_value  upload_tmp_dir "/var/www/tmp"
php_admin_value upload_max_filesize 256M
php_admin_value post_max_size 256M
```

`через php.ini, init_set(), .htaccess` то же самое сделать не удалось.